# How to load iTunes web pages on UIWebVIew

Tags: ios, uiwebview, itunes, nsuserdefaults, user-agent

How can i load iTunes on `UIWebview` i searched for this and i got this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150088/avoid-uiwebview-load-itunes-app) it has answered, but it is not working,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"some old phone or other" forKey:@"UserAgent"]];
```

it still opening the iTunes app, in the above line of code, what it this `UserAgent`..? and i also searched `UserAgent` but i don't get what is `UserAgent` key and why to  register this key for `NSUserDefaults`. What is the value to be set for key `UserAgent`..?,.. or it is recommend to open the iTunes link on iTunes app,,,? any one worked on this ..?, can u please help how can i achieve this ..

i am using this for iPad application

Comment: http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/01/itunes-deep-links-demystified-how-to.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133593/uiwebview-links-opening-in-safari

Comment: @iPatel thank you for links, where first link is about how linking iTunes with the app and second link is about blocking or suppressing the opening of iTunes app, i just want t load iTunes web pages on UIWebview